# Selecting data based on 2 different criteria

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like this....

```
ClientNo       ApptStrt        ApptEnd        Type
1774           1/27/2016       1/27/2016      A
1774           1/27/2016       1/27/2016      B
1174           2/2/2016        2/2/2016       B
186            1/12/2016       1/12/2016      A
186            1/11/2016       1/11/2016      B
```

This table contains tens of thousands of records that looks like the data above. My goal is to find all client records that have both Type A and B, only where ApptStrt for A and B is the same.

In this case client 1774 has type A & B - and it just so happens that both ApptStrt dates are the same, unlike ClientNo 186 that has different ApptStrt dates, even though has both Types.

Desired end result

```
ClientNo       ApptStrt        ApptEnd        Type
1774           1/27/2016       1/27/2016      A
1774           1/27/2016       1/27/2016      B
```

'This is what I've been trying to do

```
Select x1.ClientNO, x1.ApptStrt, x1.ApptEnd, x1.Type from TblClientRecords X1
inner join tblClientRecords X2
On x1.appStrt = x2.appStrt
where x1.type in (A,B)
```

I'm trying to be more specific though - especially with TYPE as there are other types as well. So it would be best to somehow be able to make sure that it only looks for A and B. I'm looking for only those specific ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by` client no and apptstrt and check if both the types exist.

```
select clientno,apptstrt
from tblClientRecords
group by clientno,apptstrt
having count(case when type = 'A' then 1 end) >= 1
and count(case when type = 'B' then 1 end) >= 1
```

To get the full row, join the previous result to the original table.

```
select t.* 
from tblClientRecords t
join (
select clientno,apptstrt
from tblClientRecords
group by clientno,apptstrt
having count(case when type = 'A' then 1 end) >= 1
and count(case when type = 'B' then 1 end) >= 1
) x on x.clientno=t.clientno and x.apptstrt=t.apptstrt
```

Answer (score 1):

Above works but seems overly complex.
If you join the table to itself and limit output in the ON- you can get this without having to deal with GROUP_BY clauses. 
This is also a general case that can then be applied to a lot of situations.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tblClientRecords  as A
JOIN
    tblClientRecords  AS B
        ON 
        A.ClientNo = B.ClientNo
        AND A.ApptStrt = B.ApptStrt
        AND A.[Type] = A
        AND B.[Type] = B
```

Comment: Good solution as long as he is fine with A and B in one row. In desired result he had two separate rows.

Comment: @mrek I assumed it was ok since the rows will always be duplicates with A and B, if there was a third type then the code gets more complex but can follow the same logic. If for some reason that was the desired format create duplicate rows with UNION ALL and adding ,'A' and ,'B' to each select

Answer (score 1):

You've joined two aliases on *appStrt*, but need also to remember about *clientno*. Then you can add as well requirement that *type* from x1 should not be equal to *type* from x2. And as you can have more types than *A* and *B* you need to repeat your condition *x1.type in (A,B)* for x2 as well.

Personally I recommend to use those conditions with *exists* instead of *join*:

```
select x1.ClientNO, x1.ApptStrt, x1.ApptEnd, x1.Type from TblClientRecords X1
where  x1.type in (A,B) and exists (select * from tblClientRecords X2
where x1.ClientN = x2.ClientN and x1.appStrt = x2.appStrt and x1.type <> x2.type
and x2.type in (A,B))
```